# Loading scss into a string variable with create-react-app 2.0 without ejecting

Tags: create-react-app

Is it possible to load scss into a variable without ejecting?
I'm using typescript a have tried loading the styles like this:

```
import * as styles from './index.scss';
```

but `styles` is just an empty object...

(I've created a globals.d.ts file with the following contents allow for importing the scss)

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: {[className: string]: string};
  export = content;
}
```

Ultimately I need to styles loaded into a string i.e. `styles.toString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loading the styles into a string variable, I had to eject and remove the style-loader when testing for css/scss in `webpack.config.(dev|prod).js`. Not sure it can be done otherwise.